# Select only new event date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to select records where there is only a payment date in the current month, by this there can't be any other records historically, so if someone pays this month but has paid in the previous month then this is not returned.

Pretty sure I'll kick myself for not figuring this out...

Comment: Could you give me the definition of your table?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @currentMonth int, @currentYear
select @currentMonth = MONTH(GETDATE()), @currentYear = YEAR(GETDATE())

select * from your_table 
where MONTH(paymentDate) = @currentMonth and YEAR(paymentDate) = @currentYear 
and id not in 
     (select id from your_table where MONTH(paymentDate) < @currentMonth and 
      YEAR(paymentDate) == @currentYear OR YEAR(paymentDate) != @currentYear)
```

Comment: You must filter on year as well. Otherwise you will get transactions from the same month in all years.

Comment: this will only return payments in the current month and doesn't touch if there where payments previously.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following correlated query:

```
declare @ms date, @me date

set @ms = getdate()
set @ms = dateadd(day, 1-datepart(day, @ms), @ms)
set @me = dateadd(month, 1, @ms)

select t.*
from TableName t
where t.PaymentDate >= @ms and t.PaymentDate < @me
    and not exists (
        select 1 from TableName t2
        where t2.PayerID = t.PayerID and t2.PaymentDate < @ms
    )
```